# Why is the result when multiplying cosine by a number is negative?

Tags: trigonometry

When multiplying the cosine of an angle by any number, the result is originally negative, but I solve it in my calculator and it gave me positive. What is the explanation?

[Example calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5umUx.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps one calculator is working with radians and the other one with degrees.

Comment: I think you need to give more details, your question is very unclear.

Comment: Very unclear. Please give numerical examples.

Comment: @Deepak Unclear? She has used Photomath to compute $6\cos 22$. But her calculator yields a different result. It is clear that she is solving some trignometry problem and some hypothenuse is $6$. It is *clear*. And she has entered here and asked that. The least thing we must do is not saying that her question is "unclear".

Comment: @JeanMarie I'd say that $6\cos 22=-5.99976$ is a numerical example. Don't you agree?

Comment: @ajotatxe Maybe you have sharper eyes than I, but I didn't even see the linked image until now. The link consists of a single character, and I think having missed it is understandable. Regardless, that could easily have been written out in the post, formatted with Mathjax as is proper.

Comment: @Deepak She is probably 15 or 16 years old, by the question. MathJax??? Are you kidding?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself well, as the first comment says my calculator was in degrees and should be in radians, with that I managed to find the result. Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: @ajotatxe The assessment of quality of a question should not depend on such assumptions. Anyway, it is pointless arguing about this, you have your opinion, I have mine. That's why this is a diverse community, with each of the eligible members having a vote. Cheers. EDIT: and now you're being needlessly hostile. I am not replying to you any further.

Comment: @ajotatxe they probably didn't notice the $1$ is hyperlinked (I did not either at first)

Comment: @ajotatxe I hadn't clicked on the little blue $\color{blue}{[1]}$ ! I had read "negative 1"... One thing is sure, her book (?) gives a completely silly answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost surely, Photomath is working with radians. In fact $22\approx7\pi$, so $\cos 22$ radians is very close to $-1$. This matches with your negative result $-5.99976$.

If you are solving a triangle, probably you should use degrees. The length of a leg can't be negative.

Answer (score 0):

As ajotatxe mentioned in the comments, you may have confused [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) with [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)) (two different units used to measure angles).

For example:

$$cos(100 \text { radians}) = 0.862 \ldots$$

$$cos(100°) = -0.174 \ldots$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have edited your post, but as @JoséCarlosSantos mentioned, I would suggest learning how to write mathematics on MSE as it would greatly improve presentation and clarity.

Comment: thx, I am a new user, and I'll try it